# Tracking web app in native iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, e-commerce, analytics, tracking

I have recently got my app accepted into the apple app store but the problem I am having is that my app is a fully transactional e-commerce store and I cant seem to tell the difference between normal sales from the server and sales from the app.

Is there anyway to tell the difference between an iPhone app sale and a sale in mobile safari?

if someone could give me an answer on this I would be most appreciative.

thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

The user agent string used by the iphone will be quite distinct, I've seen things like

```
 appname/1.2 CFNetwork/485.10.2 Darwin/10.3.1
```

Which should be enough for your purposes.

Comment: +1 just to clarify, the user-agent from a mobile device will almost always be distinct(not just iPhone).